# Removing pimples/soften image/replacing image pixels with surrounding pixels

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

http://beautifulapps.mobi/acne/

And another example here:

[image: Other Example that has same functionality]

I need to implement such acne removal in my own app too. I tried searching on Stack Overflow and came across dozens of questions but they were related to simple image filters. I thought of applying blur but then I gave a good thought and I think blurring won't be the solution here.

Brad GPUImage library is also there. It has lots of effects, I have gone through them not helpful in my situation. It's possible that I might have missed an important one. How can I achieve this?

Comment: check http://www.ehow.com/how_7390281_use-blur-skin-photoshop-cs3.html for a description of how to do this in Photoshop, then try applying this same methodology with GPUImage (e.g. duplicate, Gaussian blur the dup, then blend/composite back with the original).

Answer (score 3):

The GPUImage framework will help you. Have a look at the filters described here: [JH Labs](http://www.jhlabs.com). What you need to do is (this is not easy; lots of work)

1. Figure out face skin-tone. Use the face-detection algorithm to locate the face and then sample flesh tone from forehead and cheek area.
2. For each skin-tone type, you need to have a range of colors you consider shades of the skin.
3. In your filter, if the pixel in question falls within the skin-tone range, then apply minimum or median filter (essential a noise elimination filter; not a blurring filter - that will get you no where). You may have to apply multiple passes of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps for concept. I did pimple remover as a python Opencv project, below is the code(I have put explanation for the code where required):

```
from fileinput import filename
import cv2 as cv
from cv2 import waitKey
from cv2 import destroyAllWindows
from cv2 import VideoWriter
from cv2 import minMaxLoc
from more_itertools import padded
import numpy as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mat
import math
from sympy import fps


# OpenCV Utility Class for Mouse Handling
# With functions for to mouse callback to work on
class Sketcher:
    def __init__(self, windowname, dests, colors_func):
        self.prev_pt = None
        self.windowname = windowname
        self.dests = dests
        self.colors_func = colors_func
        self.dirty = False
        self.show()
        cv.setMouseCallback(self.windowname, self.on_mouse)

    # Displaying windows
    def show(self):
        cv.imshow(self.windowname, self.dests[0])
        cv.imshow(self.windowname + ": mask", self.dests[1])

    # onMouse function for Mouse Handling
    def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        pt = (x, y)
        if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.prev_pt = pt
        elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            self.prev_pt = None

        # Draw the line between mouse clicks
        if self.prev_pt and flags & cv.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
            for dst, color in zip(self.dests, self.colors_func()):
                cv.line(dst, self.prev_pt, pt, color, 5)
            self.dirty = True
            self.prev_pt = pt
            self.show()


src = cv.imread("C:/Python/Python_OpenCV/pics/blemish.png", -1)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.imshow(src, cmap="gray")
plt.title("Original Image")

if src is None:
    print("Failed to load the image: {}".format(filename))

# Create the copy mage

src_mask = src.copy()

# Create a black copy of the original image
# Acts as a mask
inpaintMask = py.zeros(src.shape[:2], py.uint8)
# Create sketch using Opencv Utility Class:Sketcher
sketch = Sketcher("image", [src_mask, inpaintMask], lambda:((255, 255, 25), 255))

while True:
    ch = cv.waitKey()
    if ch == 27:
        break
    if ch == ord("t"):
        # Use Fast Marching Algorithm method
        res = cv.inpaint(src= src_mask, inpaintMask= inpaintMask, inpaintRadius= 3, flags= cv.INPAINT_TELEA)
        cv.imshow("Inpaint output using FMM", res)
    
    if ch == ord("n"):
        # Use Navier-Stokes Algorithm method
        res = cv.inpaint(src= src_mask, inpaintMask= inpaintMask, inpaintRadius= 3, flags= cv.INPAINT_NS)
        cv.imshow("Inpaint using NS technique", res)
    
    if ch == ord("r"):
        # ord = Return the Unicode code point for a one-character string.
        # original image
        src_mask[:] = src
        inpaintMask[:] = 0
        sketch.show()


plt.show()
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```